# Change phantomjs screen reslotion

Tags: phantomjs

I have do some stuff like:

```
   page.onInitialized = function(){
         window.screen = {width:320, height:640}
    })
```

It works just in one DOM , if the document has another DOM(like a document has a iframe). that one's screen is 1024 * 768. I cant change it in iframe before iframe's document loaded.

Updated:

Phantomjs default screen resolution is 1024 * 768 when it run in background,but I want to change it to 320 * 640.

And, [viewportSize](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html)  effectively simulates the size of the window(NOT SCREEN RESOLUTION).

Answer (score 1):

You can change it only within `onInitialized` callback:

```
function on_init (page){
var width='320',height='640';

//page.viewportSize = {width:width,height:height}
page.evaluate(function (width,height){
screen = {width:width,height:height,availWidth:width,availHeight:height};// window.screen object
//innerWidth=width;  innerHeight=height;   outerWidth=width;  outerHeight=height;
},width,height);};

var page = require('webpage').create(); page.onInitialized=function(){on_init(page)}
```

Comment: I know this solution，this setting just impact on current document.if the document has a another DOM(like a iframe).the iframe is unaffected. I need a solution for all document

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set the viewport default size before opening the page?

```
page.viewportSize = { width: 320, height: 640 };
```

Comment: Sorry, this way to set windows size not resolution.

Comment: Isn't is the same? `It is usually quoted as width × height, with the units in pixels` [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution) Please update your answer with more details as to what you're trying to accomplish and provide an URL if possible.

Comment: for example, if you resize your window of browser,the resolution is not change.